# combobox auto complete in Arabic vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have combobox get item data from datasource but item in english and arabic like

```
Liquid soup صابون سائل
Cigarate سجائر 
Shampoo شامبو
```

example when write L will give me all item that started with l word . I need when i write the word ص the combo give me all item that start with ص word ...

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DAL().selectDataTable("SELECT mateName, mateID FROM meterials;")
comboSamType.DataSource = dt
comboSamType.DisplayMember = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
comboSamType.ValueMember = dt.Columns(1).ColumnName
```

[image: [enter image description here]]

Comment: Where is type drop down come from? What is content of mateName at meterials?